# How to draw on the screen without VESA, GOP, UGA

Tags: osdev

I recently took up osdev, and I had a question. How to draw a basic Windows and Linux video driver on the screen, regardless of the type of boot (UEFI, BIOS). I want to write something like this, and I wonder if they create their own frame buffer or somehow turn on one video mode always.

I tried to find how to create a frame buffer, how to enable VESA on UEFI or GOP in the BIOS, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: "How to draw a basic Windows and Linux video driver on the screen" Sorry, this is *huge*, and I don't think you realize how huge your question is.